# Read result from an exported function callback

Tags: node.js, callback, mongoose

I can't find a solution to this simple issue: I want to call a function exported from an external .js and save the output. I've done the following:

db.js

```
function findMessages () {
    allMsg = mongoose.model('allMsg');
    allMsg.find(function (err, message) {
       console.log('here is ok');
       return message;
    });
};

exports.returnMessages = findMessages;
```

app.js

```
var db = require( './db' );

app.get('/message', function(req, res){
  var messages = db.returnMessages();
  console.log('Nothing here (undefined): ' + messages);
});
```

How can I read messages in app.js?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: You cannot. That's not how callbacks work.

You need to change `findMessages()` to accept a callback function.

```
function findMessages (callback) {
    allMsg = mongoose.model('allMsg');
    allMsg.find(function (err, message) {
       callback(message)
    });
};

// app.js
app.get('/message', function(req, res) {
    db.returnMessages(function(messages) {
        console.log(messages);
    });
});
```

Comment: You should also handle the potential error in the find() function, either in the findMessages() function itself or by also passing that into the callback.

Comment: True, I'd just pass the callback directly to `find`.